# MySQL query to Count Number of Users in Age Group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am calculating the age of my users in MySQL and I am running into a little problem. I am able to successfully calculate the age of each user, however, when I try to count the number of users who are part of each age group, that is when I run into trouble. Here is my query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS "Number of Users", 
           YEAR(CURDATE()) - 
           YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) - 
           (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), 5)) 
             AS Age
    FROM user 
GROUP BY Age
```

I feel like I am close, it just is not working for me. How would I count the number of users in each age group?

Comment: What are you using for age groups?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you are asking. Can you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: Can you make one sqlfiddle for this

Comment: Please explain "it just is not working for me". What's the issue?

Comment: You say you want to count the number of users in each group - what is an age group? How many groups are there? How are they defined? The answer to your question ("how do I count the number of users who are part of each age group") depends on what the age groups are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery to access calculated column aliased Age in `Group By` clause

```
SELECT Age,COUNT(user_id) AS "Number of Users"

FROM
(
    SELECT userid,
           YEAR(CURDATE()) - 
           YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) - 
           (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), 5)) 
             AS Age
    FROM user
) as Z 
GROUP BY Age
```